# Bulma Navbar Dropdowns Not Working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, bulma

When I navigate to the navbar section of the Bulma documentation (https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/) using Internet Explorer 11, the navbar link dropdown menus do not display even when they are given the class "is-active." This is also my experience with my own code. Is there some polyfill or fix for this?

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this same issue, while using Bulma in my Gatsby project. I am not sure what exactly is causing it, but luckily I was able to patch it fairly easily. The style rules that come along with the Bulma "is-hoverable" class are super simple. I just added this to my stylesheet (or styled component in my case):

```
    @media (min-width: 1088px) {
     .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown {
        display: block;
        }
    }
```

This replicates what is already in the Bulma styles.

You could, of course, zazz this up a bit with some other properties and transitions, etc. Of course, I realize this kind of negates the convenience of using a CSS framework and having the ability to just throw some classes on an element to make it do stuff.

I have seen elsewhere that there were IE11 issues with Bulma previously. Can't remember what they were or if they were resolved. I guess what I am getting at here is that I might not count on the good folks at Bulma making this a priority if it has been identified as an issue. Might be worth look into identifying the cause and making a pull request.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by browsers ignoring whole sets of CSS selectors if any one of them contains a selector they don't understand.

In this case the CSS that is responsible for making the navigation appear on hover is this:

```
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed,
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed,
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus-within .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus-within .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed,
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
```

IE11 will ignore the whole thing because [it doesn't understand the `:focus-within` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

Simply removing the selectors that contain `:focus-within` will fix it, like this:

```
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed,
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-hoverable:focus .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed,
.navbar.is-spaced .navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown,
.navbar-item.is-hoverable:hover .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
```

This will obviously remove the functionality for all browsers, instead you can [polyfill it](https://github.com/jsxtools/focus-within)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar-item.is-active .navbar-dropdown.is-boxed {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

If you are using JavaScript to toggle the "is-active" class then this will work for you on all browsers including IE and Edge.